# How to Calculate Rolling Average and Maintain Last Two Distinct Values in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a pandas DataFrame that contains daily price data, and I'm trying to calculate a rolling average over a 6-month period (using a window of 126 days). In addition to the rolling average, I want to create two additional columns:

**last_distinct_rolling_avg**: This column should hold the previous distinct rolling average value until a new distinct value is encountered.

**second_last_distinct_rolling_avg**: This column should hold the second last distinct value of the rolling average.
Here's an example of the data and the desired output:

| DateTime | Price | rolling_avg | last_distinct_rolling_avg | second_last_distinct_rolling_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2007-12-31 | 1468.36 | 1468.36 | 1468.36 | NaN |
| 2008-01-02 | 1447.16 | 1457.76 | 1468.36 | NaN |
| 2008-01-03 | 1457.76 | 1457.76 | 1468.36 | NaN |

Answer (score 1):

There is a rolling and shift methods in pandas that do what you want :

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'DateTime': ['2007-12-31', '2008-01-02', '2008-01-03'],
    'Price': [1468.36, 1447.16, 1457.76]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)

# Calculate the rolling average
df['rolling_avg'] = df['Price'].rolling(window=126, min_periods=1).mean()

# Create the additional columns
df['last_distinct_rolling_avg'] = df['rolling_avg'].loc[df['rolling_avg'].diff() != 0].shift(1)
df['second_last_distinct_rolling_avg'] = df['rolling_avg'].loc[df['rolling_avg'].diff() != 0].shift(2)

# Display the DataFrame
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a question. Do you have any idea if I use rolling max instead of rolling avg? in that case, I think this logic does not work anymore